# How to send JSON in Spring?

Tags: json, spring, rest, jakarta-ee

I tried to find how I can write in Spring to POST JSON from REST client. For example, I wrote:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{userId}/add", method = RequestMethod.POST, headers = {"content-type=application/json"})
@ResponseBody
public Map<String, String> saveUser(@RequestBody User user, BindingResult result) { 
    Map<String, String> jsonResponse = new HashMap<String, String>();
    if (result.hasErrors()) {
        jsonResponse.put("Message", "Can't add the user");
        jsonResponse.put("Code", "401");
        return jsonResponse;
    }
    userService.addUser(user);
    jsonResponse.put("Message", "Success add User");
    jsonResponse.put("Code", "200");
    return jsonResponse;
}
```

End tested it from Firefox REST client. But I saw 404 error. What am I doing wrong? Thanx for help.

Comment: What was the content of the HTTP request you sent to the server?

Comment: For example, I tried like this  
   { "id": 7,
    "token": null,
    "nameUser": "Mulder Fox",
    "dateBirth": "25.10.1975",
    "role": "ROLE_USER",
    "position": "position",
    "email": "fox@gmail.com",
    "login": "muldfox",
    "phone": "+12356565",
    "address": null,
    "organization": null,
    "interests": null
}

Comment: There's a couple of possibilities: 1) Spring is not able to parse one of your fields, 2) the fields in your JSON object do not match the fields in your User object, 3) your URL could be wrong.  If you post the entire HTTP request and your User class in your question, maybe we can narrow it down.  Also, if there's a exception stack trace in your logs, that would be helpful as well.

Comment: What is `userId` resolved to in your `RequestMapping` path?

Comment: I checked a URL and it is correct, but I have a stacktrace: org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound - No matching handler method found for servlet request: path '/user/2/add', method 'POST', parameters map[[empty]]

Comment: nicholas.hauschild , yes it is.

Comment: Now I have the following stack trace: 'org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateOptimisticLockingFailureException: Batch update returned unexpected row count from update [0]; actual row count: 0; expected: 1; nested exception is org.hibernate.StaleStateException: Batch update returned unexpected row count from update [0]; actual row count: 0; expected: 1'

Answer (score 0):

First, if the URI of your request ended with "/user/2/add", it won't map to your method, which is mapped as "/{userId}/add".  This will cause the HTTP 404 error you receive.  Instead, your URI should end with "/2/add", if the "userId" is 2.

Second, annotating the User parameter with @RequestBody is not enough for the complex User type.  You will need to convert your JSON request body into a User object.  You can accomplish this with the [MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/remoting.html#rest-message-conversion).  By declaring a bean of this type, you can use Jackson's annotations to control how the JSON is parsed into the User properties.

Comment: No, I did everything right. @RequestBody is enough, because I use Spring 3.0.x. The problem was that I didn't use header in request header when I tested it.